# Disable copy-button in Telegram pre-tag

Tags: telegram-bot

I use a Telegram-bot for sending updates from my Home Automation. I like to do some text styling for easier reading and a quick notice of special messages. Mostly I use bold, italic or underlined text, but I discovered the pre-tag for a code block. I like to use this tag for error-messages for example.

But when I tested it I used a short text, that looked fine! Now I received a longer message and a copy-button appeared...
Below an example of a short (without button) and a longer message (with button).

[image]

I don't like that button! I don't want that button!

I used the same `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags for both blocks. So it appears only based on length I think...?

Does someone know a way to make it disapear or disable it?

Comment: At the time there is no way of removing that button from a message send by a bot

Comment: try using `<code></code>` block, or use Markdown parse mode with ``` ``` tags.

Comment: @0stone0 That's a pity...I hoped it could be managed one way or another. Will have to look for another way of pretty styling then.
@AmirAref I allrady tried ```<code></code>``` but that doesn't do any styling at all, it comes out as plane text. I liked the orange frame from the ```<pre></pre>``` tag...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove this button at this time. But there is an alternative solution: use a pre-tag on each line. What I mean:

message:

```
<pre>pre block</pre>
<pre>pre block</pre>
<pre>pre block</pre>

--------------------

<pre>pre block</pre>

<pre>pre block</pre>

<pre>pre block</pre>
```

result:
[image]

By the way, even if the string takes two/three lines, it will still work without the button.

Comment: That's right, with 2 lines the button doesn't appear. That"s the way I use it now. But I can't always cut my strings in pieces...